# Extract Rectangle from image

Tags: image-segmentation

Given this image:

[image]

How can  I extract the 'rectangle' my arm is holding  up?
I know about closing, dilation and erosion etc but I still manage to get artefacts of my hand included after filtering.

The size of that rectangle can vary due to varying distance if the camera.

I am using emgucv:

```
CvInvoke.Threshold(MyImage, MyImage, 10d, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);
var element = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement( ElementShape.Cross, new Size( 3, 3 ), new Point( -1, -1 ) );     
CvInvoke.Erode( Threshold, Threshold, element, new Point( -1, -1 ), 1, BorderType.Reflect, default(MCvScalar) );
```

... and I would like image to 'roughly' look like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you define which rectangle you actually would like to get? (because I honestly don't know which)

Comment: @m +1 for helping me to improve my question

Comment: ah nice; hm, in that case, maybe try finding corners, e.g. through Hough transforms on the edges?

Comment: yes, that was where my mind was going to.  I could iterate through each point of contours and then see the pattern of alignment and of width.  I was concerned I was taking the long way round (my biggest bad habit) so, wanted to see if there was a better way through morphological functions. I will post back if I solve for other people. Off to gym :)